# Cannot run the project in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, java

```
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" 
(in directory  "/Users/zhangstudyro/Developer/Java/HiWorld"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Hi, I'm new to mac.

The report above is the problem details given by eclipse when I tried to run "HiWorld".

I can "javac" and "java" the code in Terminal. And in eclipse, I've added JDK1.6.0 which is the default JDK version to the Build Path Libraries.

Googled and SOFed for hours, but I'm still perplexed with my Eclipse on Mac.

Comment: (1) Is there a folder "/Users/zhangstudyro/Developer/Java/HiWorld"?
(2) Can you execute "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"?

Comment: At the commandline what does `which java` tell you? I also doubt that you need to manually add the JDK to the build path libraries.

Comment: @michael667 Yes, that print lines of help messages in Terminal. But the problem details given by Eclipse says that "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" can't be found in "/Users/zhangstudyro/Developer/Java/HiWorld"   .. I can't understand this.

Comment: @drjerry Thank you for helping me. "which java" tell me "/usr/bin/java".

Comment: and what does `ls -al /usr/bin/java` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with Intellij. I fixed it by changing the path to the JDK.

For me, the issue was cause by Apple changing the JDK's location when my work computer got upgraded to the latest version of Mac OS X. The new path for my JDk looks the same, but doesn't start with "/System".